# XPath syntax? InvalidSelectorException: Not a legal expression

Tags: html, xml, xpath

```
    findElement(xpath("(//input[@class='selected-flag']")).sendKeys(countryCode);
```

Is this the correct syntax for a XPath? I get the error

> Not a legal Expression

and unable to locate the element.

Comment: i do have class called Selected-flag

Comment: You need one more closing parenthesis `)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the extra opening `(`:

```
findElement(xpath("(//input[@class='selected-flag']")).sendKeys(countryCode);
                   ^
```